# Split and transform columns into aggregated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The data I have is as described below:

## Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A1", "A2"], "col2": ["B1", "B2"], "2015-1": [231, 432], "2015-2": [456, 324]})
print(df)
  col1 col2  2015-1  2015-2
0   A1   B1     231     456
1   A2   B2     432     324
```

The columns `2015-1` and `2015-2` corresponds to years and months. The data I want to transform is as below:

## Output:

```
print(df)
  col1 col2  year    month  values
0   A1   B1  2015        1     231
1   A1   B1  2015        2     456
2   A2   B2  2015        1     432
3   A2   B2  2015        2     324
```

I want to Transform the data into another dataframe without constructing a loop since the data I have contains lots of columns and rows, it takes a really long time. Is there any way to convert the input into output without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `melt` with `split` then `join` back

```
s=df.melt(['col1','col2'])
s=s.join(s.variable.str.split('-',expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Year',1:'Month'}))
  col1 col2 variable  value  Year Month
0   A1   B1   2015-1    231  2015     1
1   A2   B2   2015-1    432  2015     1
2   A1   B1   2015-2    456  2015     2
3   A2   B2   2015-2    324  2015     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
output = df.melt(id_vars=['col1', 'col2'])
output.assign(**output.variable.str.split('-', expand=True)
                           .rename(columns={0:'year', 1:'month'}))

   col1 col2  year  value  month
0   A1   B1  2015    231       1
1   A2   B2  2015    432       1
2   A1   B1  2015    456       2
3   A2   B2  2015    324       2
```

Comment: I want to ask that when I run the code, I get an Attribute error that says: ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'```. Also, what does double star behind output does here?

Comment: Fixed @nizarcan! That is dictionary unpacking, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/